# Disable small character EditText InputType

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

Is there any way to achieve like below image?
I have an EditText and i want InputType is always Caps. 
I tried using this

```
android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
```

its working fine but when i press top Arrow icon from softkeyboard(shown in below image) and start typing text will be in small character. Is there any way to **Disable** the top arrow key?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it through code as follow:

**Applying UpperCase as the only filter to an EditText**

Here we are setting the UpperCase filter as the only filter of the EditText. Notice that doing it this way you are removing all the previously added filters(maxLength, maxLines,etc).

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.AllCaps()});
```

**Adding UpperCase to the existing filters of an EditText**

To keep the already applied filters of the EditText (let's say maxLines, maxLength, etc) you need to retrieve the applied filters, add the UpperCase filter to those filters, and set them back to the EditText. Here is an example how:

```
InputFilter[] editFilters = editText.getFilters();
InputFilter[] newFilters = new InputFilter[editFilters.length + 1];
System.arraycopy(editFilters, 0, newFilters, 0, editFilters.length);
newFilters[editFilters.length] = new InputFilter.AllCaps();  
editText.setFilters(newFilters);
```

Comment: Glad to help. Mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem

Comment: @Ricardo does it not reflect the other properties which are define XML

Comment: check edited post. its full code. you only need to copy paste

Answer (score 1):

It works for me,
Try this

```
edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
edittext.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.AllCaps()});
```

Comment: Setting the InputType followed by `setFilters` is pointless unless you retrieve the previous filters. This way that first line of code works pretty much as it is not there

Answer (score 0):

You can control to respond directly to keyboard input for user actions.
Check this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/commands.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can set programmatically. Android has built-in [IntentFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.AllCaps.html) for this.

you can achieve this by using following code-:

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.AllCaps()});
```

But, there is an issue setFilters will **reset all other attributes which were set via XML** (like maxLines, inputType and other)

So, you need to set Filter like this,

```
InputFilter[] editFilters = <EditText>.getFilters();
InputFilter[] newFilters = new InputFilter[editFilters.length + 1];
System.arraycopy(editFilters, 0, newFilters, 0, editFilters.length);
newFilters[editFilters.length] = new InputFilter.AllCaps();  
//you can use another filter like for maxLength you can use
// newFilters[editFilters.length] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(10);
<EditText>.setFilters(newFilters);
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18934659/7073808) for information

This will work for you.

Comment: <YOUR_FILTER> what to put here

Comment: like for max lenth `new InputFilter.LengthFilter(10);`

Comment: Your answer might be correct but its not working for me.
Thank you for answer.

Comment: i am still getting small character

Comment: Ok ! because you are overriding your filters again Whatever ! Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

**YES** you can do something like that

you can check for every letter typed by the user if it small letter convert it to its upper one

For Example:-

if the user typed **e** replace it with **E**

Comment: how to replace if text size is very large?

Comment: you can achieve that by using **toUpperCase()** method

Comment: i want caps while typing

Comment: u can use **addTextChangedListener()** and convert text to upper case